# How to delay and re-order output? Is it possible within a list?

Tags: lists, output

I'd like to make reports using LaTeX, meaning that I would be able to take notes chronologically and that those notes would be organised in groups before being output.

I already tried to achieve this, using the `answers` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{answers}

\Newassociation{list1}{List1}{\jobname-list1}
\Newassociation{list2}{List2}{\jobname-list2}    

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{\jobname-list1}
\Opensolutionfile{\jobname-list2}

\begin{list1}
Test for list 1.  
\end{list1}

\begin{list2}
Test for list 2.  
\end{list2}

\begin{list1}
Another item for list 1.  
\end{list1}

\Closesolutionfile{\jobname-list1}
\Closesolutionfile{\jobname-list2}

\section{List 1}
\Readsolutionfile{\jobname-list1}

\section{List 2}
\Readsolutionfile{\jobname-list2}

\end{document}
```

Downside on this approach is that there is a lot of overhead, because every note is added by using an environment.  As this will be typed in realtime, that could be a problem.

So I was thinking it would be better if I could achieve the same result using a `description`-like list.  But I don't know if that's possible?

MWE:

```
\begin{regroupedDescription}
\item[list1] Test for list1
\item[list2] Test for list2
\item[list1] Another item for list1
\end{regroupedDescription}
```

Desired output:

List1:

- Test for list1
- Another item for list1

List2:

- Test for list2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `etoolbox` package has named list macros that you can use for this purpose. Note that the list names are LaTeX macros, which puts restrictions on the name (e.g., no numbers). You can put more or less arbitrary code in the lists, but it might break for certain complex input.

To print the lists you can use `\dolistloop`, see the `etoolbox` manual for details.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\listadd{\listone}{Test for list one}
\listadd{\listtwo}{Test for list two}
\listadd{\listone}{Another item for \textbf{list one} with math: $\sqrt{3x}$}

List one
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\dolistloop{\listone}
\end{itemize}

List two
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\dolistloop{\listtwo}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]